# Sort Keys in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, key

I have a Javascript Object that contains a mix of property types including simple strings, objects, arrays of objects... and so on.

I would like to sort the keys following this rule:

'Simple properties like strings or numbers appears always before more complex properties that contains arrays or objects'

I wrote the following function, that almost do what I am trying to achieve, but it converts the arrays into objects. This is not the desired behaviour. Can anybody help me to create a function that keep arrays as arrays and at the same time it sorts the objects inside arrays?

```
function sort(object){
    if (typeof object != "object" )
        return object;
    var keys = Object.keys(object);
    keys.sort(function(a,b){
            if (typeof(object[a])!== 'object') { return -1 } else { return 1 }
        });
```

Working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/u01mn2py/3/

Kind Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), an object's *own* properties [*do* have order](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) for some operations, although relying on it is rarely a good idea. If you want order, usually it's best to use an array or similar.

The order is:

> 1. Let *keys* be a new empty List.
> 2. For each own property key *P* of *O* that is an integer index, in ascending numeric index order
>
>    - Add *P* as the last element of *keys*.
> 3. For each own property key *P* of *O* that is a String but is not an integer index, in property creation order
>
>    - Add *P* as the last element of *keys*.
> 4. For each own property key *P* of *O* that is a Symbol, in property creation order
>
>    - Add *P* as the last element of *keys*.
> 5. Return *keys*.

That's for "own" properties. <s>I don't think there are any externally-available operations that define a required order for all properties including inherited ones. (`for-in` is not required to follow the order above, not even in ES2015+.)</s> As of ES2019, `for-in` [does have a defined order](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-enumerate-object-properties) *(with some exceptions)*.

This means that it's probably possible to do what you asked, on a compliant engine, provided none of our keys qualifies as as an integer index.

JSON still has no order, but `JSON.stringify` is required by the JavaScript spec to use the order described above.

I'm not saying I *suggest* it. :-)

```
function sort(object) {
    // Don't try to sort things that aren't objects
    if (typeof object != "object") {
        return object;
    }

    // Don't sort arrays, but do sort their contents
    if (Array.isArray(object)) {
        object.forEach(function(entry, index) {
            object[index] = sort(entry);
        });
        return object;
    }

    // Sort the keys
    var keys = Object.keys(object);
    keys.sort(function (a, b) {
        var atype = typeof object[a],
            btype = typeof object[b],
            rv;
        if (atype !== btype && (atype === "object" || btype === "object")) {
            // Non-objects before objects
            rv = atype === 'object' ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            // Alphabetical within categories
            rv = a.localeCompare(b);
        }
        return rv;
    });

    // Create new object in the new order, sorting
    // its subordinate properties as necessary
    var newObject = {};
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        newObject[key] = sort(object[key]);
    });
    return newObject;
}
```

Live Example (I also [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u01mn2py/5/)):

```js
function sort(object) {
    // Don't try to sort things that aren't objects
    if (typeof object != "object") {
        return object;
    }
    
    // Don't sort arrays, but do sort their contents
    if (Array.isArray(object)) {
        object.forEach(function(entry, index) {
            object[index] = sort(entry);
        });
        return object;
    }
    
    // Sort the keys
    var keys = Object.keys(object);
    keys.sort(function (a, b) {
        var atype = typeof object[a],
            btype = typeof object[b],
            rv;
        if (atype !== btype && (atype === "object" || btype === "object")) {
            // Non-objects before objects
            rv = atype === 'object' ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            // Alphabetical within categories
            rv = a.localeCompare(b);
        }
        return rv;
    });
    
    // Create new object in the new order, sorting
    // its subordinate properties as necessary
    var newObject = {};
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        newObject[key] = sort(object[key]);
    });
    return newObject;
}

var object = {
    family: [{
        home: {
            city: 'Madrid'
        },
        birth: {
            city: 'Madrid'
        },
        name: 'John',
        age: 32

    }, {
        home: {
            city: 'London'
        },
        birth: {
            city: 'Paris'
        },
        name: 'Marie',
        age: 25
    }],
    name: 'Dani',
    age: 33
};
var sortedObject = sort(object);
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(sortedObject, null, '\t');
```

```html
<pre id="container">
</pre>
```

*(You didn't ask for alphabetical within categories, but it seemed a reasonable thing to throw in.)*

That works for me on current Chrome, Firefox, and IE11.

Comment: I only need to display object as ordered JSON (following my rule), but JSON.stringify has not any kind of sort options. How can I do that?

Comment: @wildbyte: Right. Properties have no order in JSON, either. If you want a JSON string listing the properties in a particular order, you have to build your own function to do that. (I had to do this a while back, but sadly can't share that code. But it's not all that hard, you can use `JSON.stringify` for parts of it, but you have to define the recursion and iteration. Took about 15 lines of code.)

Comment: @wildbyte: I've updated the answer now that ECMAScript 2015 has been finalized.

Answer (score 0):

I know I can't relay on javascript properties order, but I need visually to show sorted JSON. Solved in this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/u01mn2py/4/

```
function sort(object){
    if (typeof object != "object" ) // Not to sort the array
        return object;
    var keys = Object.keys(object);
    keys.sort(function(a,b){
            if (typeof(object[a])!== 'object') { return -1 } else { return 1 }
        });
    if( Object.prototype.toString.call( object ) === '[object Array]' ) {
        var newObject = [];
     } else {
        var newObject = {}; }

     for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
            newObject[keys[i]] = sort(object[keys[i]])
      }
    return newObject;
}
```