# Sort javascript array object by different key

Tags: javascript

I've been looking for a while and want a way to sort a Javascript object like this:

```
[{"a":"111","C":"333","B":"222"},{{"A":"111","C":"333","B":"222"}]
```

and sort is alphabetically by name to get:

```
[{"a":"111","B":"222","C":"333"},{{"A":"111","B":"222","C":"333"}]
```

Please suggest any solution

Comment: You can't sort javascript object.

Comment: Sorting an objects properties makes no sense. It's totally irrelevant. Do you mean JSON?

Comment: I think most important question here is **why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered here:

[Sort Keys in Javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623333/sort-keys-in-javascript-object)

Basically, you can't sort the keys in a JavaScript object. They are unordered. You can think of it essentially as a hash. You have to extract it into an array in order to sort.

```
var obj = {a: 'Hi', b: 'There'};
Object.keys(obj).sort().map(k => { 
  var foo = {}; 
  foo[k] = obj[k]; 
  return foo; 
});
```

That will give you an array that looks like this: `[{a: 'Hi'}, {b: 'There'}]`. And that's about the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

actually you can sort it but only in case if your keys are numeric strings.

here you can see other solutions

[Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)