# How to transform object into sorted array by Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, lodash

How to transform `{2:'b',3:'c',1:'a'}` into `[{1:'a'},{2:'b'},{3:'c'}]` by lodash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fairly trivial using `Object.keys` + `Array.map`, you really don't need lodash:

```js
const obj = {2:'b',3:'c',1:'a'};
const arr = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({ [key]: obj[key] }))

console.log(arr)
```

Regarding the lack of a `sort` function, the above code is exploiting the fact that numerically indexed Object keys are (per the spec) stored sequentially. Check the order for yourself:

```js
console.log({2:'b',3:'c',1:'a'})
```

Here is the relevant portion of [the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys)

> 9.1.12 [[OwnPropertyKeys]] ( )
>
> When the [[OwnPropertyKeys]] internal method of O is called the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let keys be a new empty List.
> 2. For each own
>      property key P of O that is an integer index, in ascending numeric
>      index order
>
>    2a. Add P as the last element of keys.

Comment: I know object keys are not assumed to be sorted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623333/sort-keys-in-javascript-object), but I didn't know Object.keys are typically sorted. Where can I find more info about this??

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to the spec and the relevant portion @kevlai22. Note that this only pertains to numerical indices

Comment: No problem @kevlai22, glad to help out! :)

Answer (score 2):

With upcoming Javascript with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), you could map a new array with single objects.

```js
var data = {2:'b',3:'c',1:'a'},
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
        .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With lodash, you could use

- [`_.chain`](https://lodash.com/docs/#chain),
- [`_.toPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/#toPairs),
- [`_.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/#sortBy),
- [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/#map) and
- [`_.fromPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/#fromPairs)

```js
var data = {2:'b',3:'c',1:'a'},
    result = _
        .chain(data)
        .toPairs(data)
        .sortBy([0])
        .map(o => _.fromPairs([o]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lodash is not really necessary to accomplish what you want, but I'm still adding it anyway and add a sorted function. I've also included the native JavaScript way.

```js
const obj = {b: 3, c: 2, a: 1};


const sortByKeys = object => {
  const keys = Object.keys(object)
  const sortedKeys = _.sortBy(keys)

  return _.map(sortedKeys, key => ({ [key]: object[key]}))
}

// the lodash way, and sorted
console.log(sortByKeys(obj))

// simpler way
const result = Object.keys(obj)
  .map(key => ({ [key]: obj[key] }))
  
 console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use lodash? Just use regular Javascript. Solution can be cleaned up a bit but the idea is to loop through your object and push your desired format into a new array. I also throw the sorting in there for convenience, but feel free to re-factor to your liking.

```
const obj = {2:'b',3:'c',1:'a'}

let newArr = [];
for (var key in obj) {
  newArr.push({[key]: obj[key]})
  newArr.sort((a, b) => a[key] > b[key])
}
console.log(newArr)
```