# After parsing month list sequence get changed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Received json encode object from server side in php MONTHLY_FORMAT, read that object  in jquery as

```
var MONTHLY_FORMAT = '<?php echo $MONTHLY_FORMAT; ?>';
```

Here in console get output like this:

> {"01":"January","02":"February","03":"March","04":"April","05":"May","06":"June","07":"July
>   ","08":"August","09":"September","10":"October","11":"November","12":"December"}

but after doing JSON parse

```
var MONTHLY_FORMAT_PARSE = JSON.parse( MONTHLY_FORMAT );
```

return output like

> {10: "October", 11: "November", 12: "December", 01: "January", 02:
>   "February", 03: "March", 04: "April", 05: "May", …}

How would I get the month json object list in proper month sequence ?

Comment: have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623333/sort-keys-in-javascript-object

Comment: The problem is the "number" is actually interpreted as a string... I try to parse it in PHP and get the same result as well... You can force to parse the key in PHP as an int.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
const ordered = {};
Object.keys(MONTHLY_FORMAT_PARSE).sort().forEach(function(key) {
    ordered[key] = MONTHLY_FORMAT_PARSE[key];
});
```

(NOTE: The proper month sequence will now be in the variable "ordered ")

Comment: Thank you for replying !

I have tried this sorting but when we iterate in each loop it will give first value as October.

 $.each(ordered, function(index,value){
              console.log(value);
   });


output: 
October
VM6685:161 November
VM6685:161 December
VM6685:161 January.....

This is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but since it's not properly answered, i want to just clarify to anyone else that ever come across this doubt:

**Objects have key sorting naturally in specific contexts, since it's not wise to trust it, if you want to maintain your data sorted in a specific sequence use an Array instead.**

Here some snippet with two possible solutions (one still using objects, but not really indicated, and the other with an array of months):

```js
// If you want to stick with the object key sorting, even it being not really trustable, simply remove the '0' in the beginning of each numeric key in your JSON string (if this don't causes any kind of trouble in your context)
let obj1 = JSON.parse(`{"01":"January","02":"February","03":"March","04":"April","05":"May","06":"June","07":"July ","08":"August","09":"September","10":"October","11":"November","12":"December"}`.replace(/"0/g,'"'));

console.log(obj1);
/* Output:

{
  "1": "January",
  "2": "February",
  "3": "March",
  "4": "April",
  "5": "May",
  "6": "June",
  "7": "July ",
  "8": "August",
  "9": "September",
  "10": "October",
  "11": "November",
  "12": "December"
}

*/

// Using array to mantain the desired element sort, using the received object as it comes from your PHP server
let obj2 = JSON.parse(`{"01":"January","02":"February","03":"March","04":"April","05":"May","06":"June","07":"July ","08":"August","09":"September","10":"October","11":"November","12":"December"}`);

let monthList = Array(12).fill(0).map( (m, i) => obj2[`${i+1}`.padStart(2,'0')]);

console.log(monthList);

/* Output:
[
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July ",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"
]
*/
```