# How to create a Javascript Object with sorted keys in a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Name VIC",
    "state": "Victoria"
  },
  {
    "name": "Name NSW",
    "state": "New South Wales"
  }
]
```

I need to create an object from the array, with the `state` as a key, and **sorted**.

```
{
  "New South Wales": [
    {
      "name": "Name NSW",
      "state": "New South Wales"
    }
  ],
  "Victoria": [
    {
      "name": "Name VIC",
      "state": "Victoria"
    }
  ],
}
```

Notice that the `NSW` state has to be first in the object, but it is *not the first item* in the array. So after using loop through the array to create an object, the result is that the `Victoria` state appears first. I know that I can sort the result object, with many more codes. But is there any ways to create an object, whereas the keys are sorted immediately? (please check my code below)

```
function () {
  let result = {}
  array.forEach((item) => {
    if (!result[item.state]) {
      result[item.state] = []
    }
    result[item.state].push(item)
  })
  return result
}
```

**Update**
Please read my question again. I know that there are a lot of ways for sorting the keys, but it's not what I meant. I want the keys to be sorted right in the loop, not after the object is created.

Comment: There are no sorted objects

Comment: You use an array for sorted list, but then you dont have specific keys then.
You can use an object for a named list, but that is not a garanteed ordered list.

Comment: so have you tried to sort the array and assign keys from sorted array? Perhaps those will be sorted in this case. However, like the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/q/29623333/3995261 suggests, it's hardly a good idea to rely on the keys being sorted

Comment: @JonasWilms ES6 guarantees key insertion order remains so you actually can use object keys for sorting in ES6, ES5 did not guarantee object key order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const array = [
  {
    "name": "Name VIC",
    "state": "Victoria"
  },
  {
    "name": "Name NSW",
    "state": "New South Wales"
  }
];

const states = array => array.sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name ? -1 : a.name > b.name ? 1 : 0).reduce((result, state) =>  { result[state.state] = state; return result; }, {});

console.log(states(array))
```

Comment: one should note that every mutation changes the order

Comment: @JonasWilms, one should note that they are peddling out of date information, ES6 guarantees key order and object can now be used for sorted data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.fromEntries` to create such an object. But one thing to note here is that Object does not have sorted keys.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "name": "Name VIC",
    "state": "Victoria"
  },
  {
    "name": "Name NSW",
    "state": "New South Wales"
  }
];

var newData = Object.fromEntries(data.map(el => [el.state, el]));

console.log(newData);
```